# Miracles through natural means (part 2)

Tags: miracle, natural-phenomenon

This is a follow up to [my previous question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70768/miracles-through-natural-means).

Does anyone know of any sources where modern scientists and/or Rabbonim with relevant knowledge have discussed various possibilities for how overt miracles may have occurred through natural means?  I'm particularly interested in Kriat Yam Suf and the Eser Makot, but I'd like to know if there have been discussions of other overt nissim too.  I mean proper analysis of the feasibility of whether a certain method could happen through nature, not just a couple of throwaway sentences mentioning something in general terms.

Answer (score 3):

As an example, there actually is a "scientific" explanation for the splitting of the Yam Suf. The point is that a wind could have blown and uncovered a ridge of land across the sea. Hashem took this and changed it to be sufficient for the entire Bnei Yisrael as well as adding the miracles specified by the midrashim. It also kept the Egyptians away until they crossed as well as making the timing exact.

[Scientists Explain Red Sea Parting and Other Miracles](http://abcnews.go.com/Technology/story?id=99580&page=1)

> In the latest attempt to lend scientific credence to a supernatural
>   event, Naum Volzinger, a senior researcher at St. Petersburg's
>   Institute of Oceanography, and Alexei Androsov, a colleague based in
>   Hamburg, Germany, analyzed conditions that could have made the parting
>   of the Red Sea possible.
>
> As the biblical story goes: "And Moses stretched out his hand over the
>   sea; and the Lord caused the sea to go back by a strong east wind all
>   that night, and made the sea dry land, and the waters were divided."
>
> Volzinger and Androsov calculated that a wind blowing at the speed of
>   67 miles per hour sustained overnight could have exposed a reef that
>   existed close below the ocean surface. The Israelites could have then
>   fled over the passage before the wind died down and waters rose again,
>   blocking the way for pursuing Egyptian soldiers in their wheeled
>   chariots.
>
> Volzinger explains that some 3,500 years ago, the reef would have been
>   closer to the water's surface so it would have been exposed for just
>   the right amount of time.
>
> "It would take the Jews … four hours to cross the 7-kilometer reef
>   that runs from one coast to another," Volzinger told The Moscow Times.
>   "Then, in half an hour, the waters would come back."
>
> A miracle? Perhaps. Great timing? Certainly, argues Colin Humphreys, a
>   physicist at Cambridge University in England and author of the book,
>   The Miracles of Exodus.
>
> "I still say they're miracles," Humphreys said. "But I think the
>   miracle is in the timing."

[There is a scientific explanation for the parting of the Red Sea in Exodus](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2014/12/08/no-really-there-is-a-scientific-explanation-for-the-parting-of-the-red-sea-in-exodus/)

[Application of storm surge modeling to Moses' crossing of the Red Sea](http://gradworks.umi.com/14/68/1468999.html)

> Two case studies are presented. A reconstruction of the crossing of
>   the Red Sea by Moses and the Israelites, as described in Exodus 14,
>   shows that the eastern Nile delta of Egypt matches the Biblical
>   narrative and provides a hydrodynamic mechanism for water to remain on
>   both sides of the dry passage. The vulnerability of Manila Bay and the
>   surrounding areas to a Category 3 typhoon is evaluated and shows that
>   the simulated surge heights depend heavily on the wind direction and
>   the coastal topography.

[Dynamics of Wind Setdown at Suez and the Eastern Nile Delta](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0012481)

> Under a uniform 28 m/s easterly wind forcing in the reconstructed
>   model basin, the ocean model produces an area of exposed mud flats
>   where the river mouth opens into the lake. This land bridge is 3–4 km
>   long and 5 km wide, and it remains open for 4 hours. Model results
>   indicate that navigation in shallow-water harbors can be significantly
>   curtailed by wind setdown when strong winds blow offshore.